# How to minimize a MFC application in the OnInitDialog function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I need my MFC application to minimize on start up. I do not have much experience with MFC.

So far I have tried: removing `WS_VISIBLE`, calling `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`, and using `OnSize(...)`. Each one failed to work and/or causes the application to crash.

My next idea is to use the `PostMessage` function but I'm unsure as to what the parameters would be.

Can someone show me the parameters to minimize my application using the PostMessage function or give me another option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Post a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message with a `SC_MINIMIZE` parameter.

```
PostMessage(WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);
```